# How can I smoothly format set/dictionary for print?

Tags: python-3.x, format

So I have a list/tuple/dict/etc such as this:

```
thing = [('6', '5x^6'), ('4', '3x^4'), ('3', '2x^3'), ('2', '-3x^2')]
```

and my goal is to print it as

5x^6 + 3x^4 + 2x^3 + -3x^2

What can I put to format to continue as long as needed if I open up the data as

```
for key, number in thing:
    print('{}'.format(number))
```

or what kind of a format can understand this kind of database?

Comment: What are the conceptional steps to archive this? If the list is sorted like in your example you only need the second value in each tupel. If you want to iterate them like you want to do it will get a little bit messy. If you simple print the value with an plus sign you will print a plus sign one times more than it should be. Try it out :) Maybe the join method in python can help you (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why my "print(' + '.join(list))" wasn't working out, but it turns out I had simply made an error in the list comprehension phase.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, number in thing:
    list.append(number)
print(' + '.join(list))
```